# Simultaneously iterating through sequences of coordinate values, drawing lines between pairs of them in Turtle graphics

Tags: python, list, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, procedural-generation

In Python 3.10, I'm using Turtle graphics to write a program that currently only draws a random amount of polygonal shapes (2-5) with a random amount of points/sides (3-8) that appear on the screen in random places. To complete the program, **I want it to be able to draw connecting lines from the points of the first/preceding polygon created to the points of the next/succeeding polygon, kind of like joints on a worm-like body of polygons.**

So far, **I have a list,** `grouped_joints`**, of lists of tuples, which holds the points (or joints) for every polygon in the order both it and its points/sides were drawn.** The list would look like this if a triangle succeeded by a heptagon was drawn (the first point of the first polygon drawn always starts at 0.00, 0.00/the middle of the screen):

[[(0.00,0.00), (100.00,0.00), (50.00,-86.60)], [(112.00,151.00), (12.86,137.91), (-59.19,207.25), (-49.89,306.82), (33.75,361.63), (128.75,330.41), (163.58,236.67)]].

So, the first three points are the triangle's, the next are the heptagon's. This is then taken by a `connect_joints` function that I'm not sure what to do with.

**How would I go about taking the contents of** `grouped_joints` **and drawing a line from, in this case,**
(0.00,0.00) to (112.00,151.00),
(100.00,0.00) to (12.86,137.91),
(50.00,-86.60) to (-59.19,207.25)?

I understand that I would use a combination of my_pen.goto(), my_pen.down() and my move_pen() function to actually make the lines, but **I can't figure out the best logic for moving through a list of lists (of varying sizes) of tuples in such a way as to take the sequence of the coordinates in each sub-list and logically pair them within a looping structure...** I haven't had the time to try to even begin to figure out how to do this recursively...

For now, I don't care that not every point is connected up in some orderly way. Until I get a better grasp on the problem, I just want to be able to connect each polygon by the most immediate number of lines. All 3 points of a triangle to 3 points of a heptagon is ugly, but fine with me. Same for the other way around, if the heptagon were to have been drawn before the triangle, it's fine if it's 3 of the 7 points to all 3 points of the triangle.

Would it be easier if I used a dictionary to map each list of points to a key value and looped that way? My apologies for being so helpless, I just started working in python...

TLDR; [**any strong text**]

Below is the whole working program (76 lines) without my previous attempts at making `connect joints` work. If you run it, you'll be able to see how the polygons are drawn. Click to exit.

Thanks a lot if you've the time to take a look at this.

```
import turtle
import random
from itertools import islice

WIN_TITLE = "Summoning Wonderful Polygonal Creature..."
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
BLACK = 1, 0, 0
WHITE = 0, 0, 0


def quick_setup():
    new_screen = turtle.Screen()
    new_screen.bgcolor(WHITE)
    new_screen.title(WIN_TITLE)
    new_screen.setup(width=SCREEN_WIDTH, height=SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    new_pen = turtle.Turtle()
    return new_screen, new_pen


def move_pen(x=random.randint(-350, 350), y=random.randint(-300, 300)):
    my_pen.goto(x, y)


def rotate_pen():
    my_pen.right(random.random()*360)


def randomize_pen_color():
    random_rgb_values = (random.random(), random.random(), random.random())
    my_pen.color(random_rgb_values)


def draw_polygon(pen, length=100):
    polygon_count = random.randint(2, 5)
    all_side_counts = []
    body_joints = []
    for polygon in range(polygon_count):
        sides = random.randint(3, 8)
        all_side_counts.append(sides)
        exterior_angle = 360.0/sides
        pen.begin_fill()
        for side in range(sides):
            randomize_pen_color()
            pen.down()
            body_joints.append(pen.position())
            pen.forward(length)
            pen.right(exterior_angle)
            pen.up()
        pen.end_fill()
        rotate_pen()
        move_pen()
    return body_joints, all_side_counts


def group_joints(body_joints, all_side_counts):
    joint_slices = iter(body_joints)

    grouped_joints = [list(islice(joint_slices, each_polygon))
                      for each_polygon in all_side_counts]
    return grouped_joints


def connect_joints(grouped_joints):
    print(grouped_joints[0][0])  # How to connect in a looping structure
    print(grouped_joints[1][0])  # to this, and so on...
    print(grouped_joints)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    screen, my_pen = quick_setup()
    my_pen.speed(0)
    body_joints, all_side_counts = draw_polygon(my_pen)
    grouped_joints = group_joints(body_joints, all_side_counts)
    connect_joints(grouped_joints)
    screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not positive that this is what you mean, but you can try this.

this iterates through the shapes 2 at a time and collects one point from each shape and connects them.

```
from itertools import pairwise

def connect_joints(grouped_joints):
    for shape1, shape2 in pairwise(grouped_joints):
        for point1, point2 in zip(shape1, shape2):
            (x1,y1), (x2,y2) = point1, point2
            my_pen.penup()
            my_pen.goto(x1,y1)
            my_pen.pendown()
            my_pen.goto(x2,y2)
```

Comment: This works perfectly well for me right now. Thank you, man.

Answer (score 0):

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randrange

START_DEGREE = 360
PACE = 100

turtle = Turtle()
start_pos = turtle.heading()
angles = 3


def get_color():
   r = round(randrange(255) / 255, 2)
   g = round(randrange(255) / 255, 2)
   b = round(randrange(255) / 255, 2)
   tup = (r, g, b)
   return tup


while angles != 360:
   turtle.forward(PACE)
   turtle.right(START_DEGREE / angles)
   if turtle.heading() == start_pos:
      angles += 1
      turtle.pencolor(get_color())

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```